# Cannot create otrs ticket via generic interface

Tags: c#, http, otrs

I'm trying to create ticket in otrs system but it still return 301: Moved Permanetly. I'm using OTRS 5 Free.

My request uri: https://some.domain.com/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketREST/Ticket

And message body:

```
{
  "UserLogin": "mbar",

  "Password": "*****",

  "Ticket" : 
  {
    "Title": "raz dwa trzy",
    "Queue": "Raw",
    "Lock": "unlock",
    "Type": "Unclassified",
    "State": "new",
    "Priority": "3 normal",
    "Owner": "mbar",
    "CustomerUser": "mbar"
  },

  "Article":
  {
    "Subject" : "jakiś temat",
    "Body" : "test test tes test",
    "ContentType": "text/plain; charset=utf8"       

  }
}
```

This is my service config:

```
---
Debugger:
  DebugThreshold: debug
  TestMode: '0'
Description: Ticket Connector REST Sample
FrameworkVersion: 4.x git
Provider:
  Operation:
    SessionCreate:
      Description: Creates a Session
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Session::SessionCreate
    TicketCreate:
      Description: Creates a Ticket
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketCreate
    TicketGet:
      Description: Retrieves Ticket data
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketGet
    TicketSearch:
      Description: Search for Tickets
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketSearch
    TicketUpdate:
      Description: Updates a Ticket
      MappingInbound: {}
      MappingOutbound: {}
      Type: Ticket::TicketUpdate
  Transport:
    Config:
      KeepAlive: ''
      MaxLength: '100000000'
      RouteOperationMapping:
        SessionCreate:
          RequestMethod:
          - POST
          Route: /Session
        TicketCreate:
          RequestMethod:
          - POST
          Route: /Ticket
        TicketGet:
          RequestMethod:
          - GET
          Route: /Ticket/:TicketID
        TicketSearch:
          RequestMethod:
          - GET
          Route: /Ticket
        TicketUpdate:
          RequestMethod:
          - PATCH
          Route: /Ticket/:TicketID
    Type: HTTP::REST
RemoteSystem: ''
Requester:
  Transport:
    Type: ''
```

Can you help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missing otrs in my url what was not mentioned in documentation so I changed from https://some.domain.com/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketREST/Ticket
to
https://some.domain.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketREST/Ticket
and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an HTTP 301 error this most probably means you have not configured your web server correctly, and your server redirects to some location. OTRS typically either responds with a `200 OK`, or with a `500 Internal server error`.

Check your apache logs to see what's happening there.

I can create a ticket with `curl` like this:

```
curl "http://example.com/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Ticket?UserLogin=login&Password=sekret" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d @create_ticket.json
```

where `create_ticket.json` would be something like this:

```
{
   "Ticket" : {
      "Queue" : "Raw",
      "Priority" : "3 normal",
      "CustomerUser" : "max",
      "Title" : "REST Create Test",
      "State" : "open",
      "Type" : "Unclassified"
   },
   "Article" : {
      "ContentType" : "text/plain; charset=utf8",
      "Subject" : "Rest Create Test",
      "Body" : "This is only a test"
   }
}
```